# How does background function work in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

Yo, I hope all is fine for you!
As indicated in the title, I would like to know how `background` function works in Processing.
What is the difference between the **first program** (`background` **called before drawing the circle**) and the **second program** (`background` **called after drawing the circle**) which is the one "doesn't working"?

```
int x = 1;
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  circle(200 + x, 200, 20);
  x++;
}
```

```
int x = 1;
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  circle(200 + x, 200, 20);
  background(255);
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`background`](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html) not only defines the background color, but also fills the window with the background color. Therefore you have to call `background` before drawing the objects of the scene:

```java
void draw() {
  background(255);
  circle(200 + x, 200, 20);
  x++;
}
```

`background` clears the window and thereby all previously drawn objects. `background` does not change a state. When you call `background`, every pixel in the window is instantly changed.
(Since *processing* uses OpenGL, [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) is invoked under the hood.)

Comment: Still, according to me, it doesn't make sense... I mean, calling `background` in `setup` before drawing makes sense because `setup` is executed once, but it doesn't in `draw` function...

Comment: @Bimbouw Please read my answer. `background` actually clears the window with the background color. When you call background the every pixel in the window is changed immediately.